# How do I install the "Puppet module tool" on my local PC?

Tags: puppet

I'm looking to get started with writing a module for Puppet. Puppet's [official documentation for writing modules](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/modules_fundamentals.html#writing-modules) recommends the following:

> To write a module, we strongly suggest running `puppet module generate <USERNAME>-<MODULE NAME>`
>
> When you run the above command, the Puppet module tool (PMT) will ask a series of questions to gather metadata about your module, and creates a basic module structure for you.

Unfortunately, I don't seem to have the Puppet module tool installed on my local PC, and Puppet's docs aren't very clear on how to install it.

There are [instructions on how to set up a Puppet master and Puppet agents](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/quick_start.html#install-puppet):

> A computer that runs the Puppet Server is called the “master.” Follow these instructions to install and configure Puppet Server.
>
> A computer that runs the Puppet agent is called a “Puppet agent” or simply “agent”. The Puppet agent regularly pulls configuration catalogs from a master and applies them to the local system.

But at first glance my PC doesn't seem to fit into either of those categories. I'm not using Puppet to configure my local PC, nor am I using my local PC as a server to manage my infrastructure. I simply want to use the Puppet CLI on my local machine to generate a module.

I did also find [a GitHub repo for the Puppet module tool](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-module-tool), but the README states that the standalone tool has been deprecated as it is now built in to Puppet.

What do I need to install in order to allow the use of the Puppet module tool on my machine? Is there a Puppet SDK somewhere that I'm somehow missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally people use [bundler](http://bundler.io) to pull in Puppet and its dependencies; you then run Puppet from within your bundle.

The prerequisites you need:

- Ruby
- Ruby Gems

Then

```
$ gem install bundler
```

In your project directory:

```
$ vim Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'puppet'
```

and

```
$ bundle install
```

Now you can run:

```
$ bundle exec puppet module generate <USERNAME>-<MODULE NAME>
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I didn't even know Puppet _was_ a gem. That's not mentioned anywhere in the docs; those pages all talk about installing OS-level packages (at least for Puppet 4). Are you sure this method is still officially supported?

Comment: I actually forgot puppet could even by installed via gem until one of their leads mentioned it to me recently in a PR when I asked why ruby < 2.1 was in their head Travis. Installing puppet with your os package from the Puppetlabs repo is the preferred method for sophisticated puppet use cases, especially because everything comes with it, including the version of ruby they expect you to be using (may be 2.2 now but probably is still 2.1). All that being said, if you are doing simple puppet, then Alex's solution is not only valid but preferable.

Comment: Works great. Also it looks like `puppet module generate` creates a Gemfile with `puppet` as a dependency as part of the module, so this is definitely still supported.

Comment: If you look on the Puppet Forge, all supported modules have a Gemfile that pulls in Puppet as a Gem to be used in the development & CI/CD pipeline.  So since you're doing development here, I think use of the Gem is in fact the preferred and correct way to do this.  Probably their docs aren't really written with the developer focus in mind.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I wouldnt say gem installs is for 'non-sohisticated' use cases. It is very common to have puppet installed via gems on a workstation. Most commonly for rspec tests or beaker tests.

Comment: @ptierno I would have elaborated on what I meant by non-sophisticated, but my comment was already running long. Your example is another common use case for doing a gem install.